# Nvidia geforce 7100 Ubuntu 14.04 problems

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have a desktop I wanted to install Ubuntu on but the problem is my graphics card. I can install 14.04.1 by disabling acpi (if it's 14.04.2 won't work and 14.04.3 gets gpu lockup and freezes) and the graphics are fine but once I update to a newer kernal my resolution changes to 800x600 or something low like that. I tried installing proprietary drivers but none of them work. Any suggestions?

Comment: As Geforce 7000 series are quite old, you might want to try Xubuntu 14.04 instead.